# React component updates holds other component to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React and Redux, and I have the following sample code.

```

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Spinner />
    <TableWrapper 
      onClick={
               ()=>{sendActionToToggleIsLoading();
                    sendActionToChangeTableData()}
              }
    />
</React.Fragment>
```

```

Two components, a Spinner and a Table, they both use its own container to connect to the redux store.
The `Spinner` connects to a `isLoading` props and the `TableWrapper` connects to an array `[tableData]` in store.

The `onClick` event on `TableWrapper` will send two actions to change `isLoading` and `[tableData]` in the store and cause two components to update.

My problem is `TableWrapper` will take a bit time to update, and `Spinner` doesn't. However the `Spinner` won't update until `TableWrapper` finishes `componentDidUpdate`.

So the behavior now is after `onClick`, the two components both stuck for a while and then both update to the new state.

My goal is to let the `Spinner` to update as soon as `onClick` is triggered and the `TableWrapper` updates itself.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Surround one action with ```SetTimeOut``` makes it working, but I don't think it is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to dispatch the loading action inside `sendActionToChangeTableData()`, I cant tell you why, but it works for me

Comment: Do you mean combine two actions in one action? or create a function to call two actions? I tried the latter and didn't work.